# IF container "x" does not contain div "n"? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if its possible to make an `IF` statement, where if a container (parent div) contains/does not contain a certain div....

```
<div class="parent" id="x">need to check if div id "n" is here....</div>
```

So, `IF` the parent container ("`x`") does not contain the div "`n`", then insert it (which I already know how to do).

Is the above even possible to achieve?

JS and JQuery can be used by the way..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
   $('#id:not(:has(#n))')
```

Comment: There is a small syntax error but [This demo](http://jsbin.com/oqatag/edit#javascript,html) is clear and working.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [jQuery.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var n = document.getElementById('n');

if (jQuery.contains(x, n)) {
  // it does
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Could I just use it like this: `if (jQuery.contains"#x", "#n"))`?

Comment: @nav_nav I guess not. At least not with this syntax ))